# Browser not connecting to Springboot Websocket (sockjs)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cors, spring-websocket, sockjs

I have a SpringBoot server running on localhost:8080
and npm (serving a React app) on localhost:3000

Whenever I try to establish a websocket connection to spring, this shows up on the browser's console (Firefox Nightly):

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/ws/info?t=1522629329791. 
(Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match 
‘http://localhost:8080/ws/info’).
```

I've created a `WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer` class and tried to `setAllowedOrigins` width both null and `http://localhost:3000` (and `127.0.0.1` as well):

```
@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/ws")
            .setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
            .withSockJS();
}
```

REST requests are working fine, and I even made it to connect to the websocket in a simple node script, but within the browser I've had no luck. This is how I'm connecting in the browser (same as in script):

```
import Stomp from 'stompjs';
import SockJS from 'sockjs-client';
...
let ws = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/ws/');
let client = Stomp.over(ws);
client.connect({'some-header': 'some-data'}, (success) => {   
        //client.subscribe(...
}, (error) => {
    console.log(error)
})
```

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't manage to solve this with spring (on the server side) but I found a workaround. By using webpack (I used create-react-app, which uses webpack by default), one could simply proxy the requests to the "right" address:

```
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080/"
```

On `package.json`. Solves the problem when developing the application. But doesn't do anything for you on production. But since the webapp is served by tomcat (the compiled version (i.e., result of `npm run build` is placed on the server (`src/main/resources/static`), with a bit of configuration it's working fine.

Comment: Hi Alex, can you please give some more details what exactly you did. I mean did you set the proxy in the attribute while connecting using client.connect. Please let me know , I am also stuck to the same error

Answer (score 1):

Try `.setAllowedOrigins("*")` - allow all `ORIGIN`s:

```
/**
 * Configure allowed {@code Origin} header values. This check is mostly designed for
 * browser clients. There is nothing preventing other types of client to modify the
 * {@code Origin} header value.
 *
 * <p>When SockJS is enabled and origins are restricted, transport types that do not
 * allow to check request origin (JSONP and Iframe based transports) are disabled.
 * As a consequence, IE 6 to 9 are not supported when origins are restricted.
 *
 * <p>Each provided allowed origin must start by "http://", "https://" or be "*"
 * (means that all origins are allowed). By default, only same origin requests are
 * allowed (empty list).
 *
 * @since 4.1.2
 * @see <a href="https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6454">RFC 6454: The Web Origin Concept</a>
 * @see <a href="https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client#supported-transports-by-browser-html-served-from-http-or-https">SockJS supported transports by browser</a>
 */
StompWebSocketEndpointRegistration setAllowedOrigins(String... origins);
```

Comment: I've tried (forgot to include it in the post) but the browser still complained... This time about not allowing set-credentials when the ACCESS-CONTROL-ALLOW-ORIGIN was set to *